# Storing Values of For Loop in R and then plotting

Tags: r, loops, plot

I am trying to create a loop which stores the values for `xstar, x1[t], x2[t], x[t], a[t], and b[t]`. My goal is to ultimately plot these values and see whether x1 or x2 converge or get close to `xstar`. I am struggling with setting it up such that my code stores each relevant value in such a way that allows me to plot it. I am also struggling with being able set it such that a[t] and b[t] adjust at the end of each iteration. Below is the sequence of play for the model, in case the intuition might help illustrate what I am trying to do.

**Feel free to skip to code**
*The model is simulated between a long-living court that reviews and resolves disputes and a set of tortfeasors that decide on a level of effort. The sequence of play is as follows:

1. The court sets a negligence standard. This negligence standard is a priori set by the law, but it shares initial beliefs [a_t,b_t] ϵ [0,1] of its position.
2. N citizens draw wi. Each person draws their own respective, marginal cost of effort/care, wi, from a uniform distribution on [0,10].
3. Citizen i decides on an optimal level of effort, xi ϵ [0,1]. This decision is contingent on their cost of abatement (wi) and the current state of settled law [a,b].
4. Accident occurs with some probability and results in a legal dispute. The probability of an accident is a decreasing function of the level of effort, xi. When an accident occurs, there is a monetary value of harm, A. I assume that when an accident occurs, so does a trial/dispute.
5. Court reviews the dispute and assesses level of effort. Reviewing the case, the court learns whether that level of effort satisfies the ideal negligence standard. This process is costless.
6. Court decides on a narrow or broad ruling of the case. The legal threshold and [a_t,b_t] is updated to [a_(t+1),b_(t+1), with either a_(t+1)  or b_(t+1)=x_i
7. Repeat starting back at stage 3*

```
period = c(1:5)   ## Number of periods in the iteration of the loop.
reset1 = {
  a = c() #lower bound of belief in xstar 
  b = c() #upper bound of belief in xstar
  A = 5 ## monetary value of harm from 

  maxw = 3
  minw = 0
  wbar = (maxw+minw)/2  ##average cost

  xstar = 1 - wbar/(2*A) 
  xstar

  x1 = c()
  x2 = c()
  x  = c()

  w1 = runif(1,min = 0, max = 3)
  w2 = runif(1,min = 0, max = 3)

if(t==1){a[t]=0.3;b[t]=0.95}

}

for (t in 1:length(period)) {

  x[t] = 0 

  ##Tortfeasors problem: pick the x that will minimize your cost --- piecewise optimization. First object is if (x<=a), second is if (a<x<b), and third is when (x>=b).

x1[t] = min(c(1-(w1/(2*A)),((2+b[t])-sqrt(b[t]^2-2*b[t]+1+3*(w1/A)*(b[t]-a[t])))/3,b[t])) 

x2[t] = min(c(1-(w2/(2*A)),((2+b[t])-sqrt(b[t]^2-2*b[t]+1+3*(w2/A)*(b[t]-a[t])))/3,b[t]))

  proba1 = function(x1){(x1[t]-1)^2}  #probability of accident only given driver1's effort level.
  proba1(x1)
  probn1 = 1 - proba1(x1)      #probability of not getting in an accident given driver1's effort level
  probn1

  proba2 = function(x2){(x2[t]-1)^2}  
  proba2(x2)
  probn2= 1 - proba2(x2)
  probn2

  while (x[t]!=x1[t] & x[t]!=x2[t]) {
        x[t] = sample(c(x1[t],x2[t], 0,0),size = 1, replace = TRUE, prob = c(proba1(x1),proba2(x2), probn1, probn2)) 
        ###the x is selected based on which ever x resulted in an accident   
  }
  show(x[t])   

  rulings = if(x[t]>=b[t]) {
                ruling = print("Not Negligent")              
  } else if(x[t]<=a[t]) {
                ruling = print("Negligent")               
  } else if(x[t]>a[t] & x[t]<b[t]) {
       ruling = if(x[t]<xstar){"guilty"
  } else if(x[t]>=xstar){"not guilty"}
    show(ruling)}  


  ##legal adjustment and updating of beliefs in ambiguous region after discovery of liability
  if(ruling == "guilty") {a[t+1] = x[t]; b[t+1] = b[t]} 
  else if (ruling == "not guilty") {b[t+1] = x[t]; a[t+1]=a[t]} 
  else {a[t+1]=a[t]; b[t+1] = b[t];print("beliefs unchanged")}       
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what `a[t=1]=0.3` is supposed to do. The `t=1` is confusing, looks like a syntax error. Could you comment what that line (and the one following it) are supposed to do?

Comment: I am trying to set the ```a``` initially to 0.3, or else the following code does not take place. So essentially we begin with threshold [a,b] = [0.3,0.95], and then based on the rulings this threshold is updated and at each iteration, the citizens decide on the level of effort (```x[t]```) to exert given that particular round's updated [a,b]

Comment: Ah, so you could do `if(t == 1){ a = 0.3; b = 0.95}` But it would probably be simpler to move those two lines up to run right before the loop starts, since you don't need them to run every iteration (nor do you need to check if `t == 1` every iteration, since it starts at 1 and never comes back)

Comment: But you also need to create `a[t + 1]` and `b[t + 1]` every time through the loop. Imagine the first time through the loop, when `t = 1`. We know `a = 0.3` and `b = 0.95`, and both `a` and `b` are length 1. When we get to the bottom of the loop, if the ruling is guilty then you set `a[2] = x[1]`. But if the ruling is not guilty or neither, then `a = 0.3`... but the next time through the loop `t = 2` and the loop will look for `a[2]`, but `a` is still length 1, so `a[2]` doesn't exist. Similarly, if the ruling is guilty, `a[2]` will exist but you don't create `b[2]`.

Comment: So, at the end of the loop you need to create `a[t+1]` and `b[t+1]` regardless of the ruling. If, for some condition, you want them unchanged, you can use `a[t+1] = a[t]`.

Comment: Thank you, yes that makes sense. I think I made the right edit?

Comment: That looks right, but you still have the `a[t=1]=0.3` issue at the top of the loop.

Comment: When I move it above the for loop, I receive the following error: ```Error in t == 1 : 
  comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types```... only when I start the loop, get an error, and then try to run that line of code does it work again.

Comment: If it's before the loop, you don't need `if(t == 1)`... there is no `t` yet, hence the error. You only need `if(t == 1)` if you take the slightly worse option of putting it inside the loop. And, if it's before the loop it can be `a = 0.3; b = 0.95`, again because there is no `t` yet.

Comment: The only other error I see is the `reset1 = {` line... again, not sure what the goal is of that line. And there is no matching `}`. If you want this to be a function, you need it to be `reset1 = function() {...}`, and probably return something at the end, `return(list(a, b, x, x1, x2))`, or whatever values you want to get out of it. But it also seems to run just fine by deleting the `reset1 = {` line and addressing the other mentioned issues.